# Processing text in PHP finding a matching character

Tags: php

How can I process text with some codes.

So suppose I have text as below

```
Hello {::first_name::} {::last_name::},
How are you?
Your organisation is {::organisation::}
```

For any text between {:: and ::} should be evaluated to get its value.

I tried exploding text to array using space as delimiter and then parsing array items to look for "{::" and if found get string between "{::" and "::}" and calling database to get this field value.
So basically these will be db fields.

Below is the code I have tried

```
$msg = "Hello {::first_name::} {::last_name::},
 How are you? 
 Your organisation is {::organisation::}";

$msg_array = explode(" ", $msg);
foreach ($msg_array as $str) {
    if (strpos($str, "{::") !== false) {
        $field_str = get_string_between($str, "{::", "::}");
        $field_value = $bean->$field_str; //Logic that gets the value of the field
        $msgStr .= $field_value . " ";
    } else {
        $msgStr .= $str . " ";
    }

}

function get_string_between($string, $start, $end)
{
    $string = ' ' . $string;
    $ini = strpos($string, $start);
    if ($ini == 0) return '';
    $ini += strlen($start);
    $len = strpos($string, $end, $ini) - $ini;
    return substr($string, $ini, $len);
}
```

Comment: Why does the function `get_string_between` prefix `$string` with whitespace? what is `$bean`?

Comment: Ok, there's some funny stuff happening with your comma character, it appears to get lost, but the other translations apply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script seems fine. [Your script in fiddle](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1e4946e37ef6912558399a5a32c958032a45622f)

If you are looking for **alternative** way, you can try using preg_match_all() with str_replace(array, array, source)

```
<?php
$bean = new stdClass();
$bean->first_name = 'John';
$bean->last_name = 'Doe';
$bean->organisation = 'PHP Company';

$string = "Hello {::first_name::} {::last_name::}, How are you? Your organisation is {::organisation::}";

// find all placeholders
preg_match_all('/{::(.+?)::}/i', $string, $matches);

$placeholders = $matches[0];

//strings inside placeholders
$parts = $matches[1];

// return values from $bean by matching object property with strings inside placeholders
$replacements = array_map(function($value) use ($bean) {
    // use trim() to remove unexpected space
    return $bean->{trim($value)};
}, $parts);

echo $newstring = str_replace($placeholders, $replacements, $string);
```

Short format:

```
$string = "Hello {::first_name::} {::last_name::}, How are you? Your organisation is {::organisation::}";

preg_match_all('/{::(.+?)::}/i', $string, $matches);

$replacements = array_map(function($value) use ($bean) {
    return $bean->{trim($value)};
}, $matches[1]);

echo str_replace($matches[0], $replacements, $string);
```

And if you prefer to use a function:

```
function holder_replace($string, $source = null) {
    if (is_object($source)) {

        preg_match_all('/{::(.+?)::}/i', $string, $matches);

        $replacements = array_map(function($value) use ($source) {
            return (property_exists(trim($value), 'source')) ? $source->{trim($value)} : $value;
        }, $matches[1]);

        return str_replace($matches[0], $replacements, $string);        
    }
    return $string;
};

echo holder_replace($string, $bean);
```

OUTPUT:

```
Hello John Doe, How are you? Your organisation is PHP Company
```

[fiddle](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/10d32259dfb2d824a85853b41c32723672a54991)

Comment: @user3286692 I suggest you to change your post title to "How to replace values of placeholders dynamically in PHP"

Answer (score 0):

Or you can simply use str_replace function:

```
$data = "{:: string ::}";
echo str_replace("::}", "",str_replace("{::", "", $data));
```